# Strategies for a multi-page form?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile, ajaxform

I've been trying to make a multi-page poll with jQuery Mobile that is supposed to interact with my MySQL database through Ajax/PHP and have been having issues with it for a while now. It seems I have some problems submitting the form as a result of having it split into several pages. One requirements I need is that the page can not have a page reload.

In my first attempts I tried to divide the pages up into the following:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
```

This however failed so many times no matter how I tried to code it. I can not get the submit button to work and I think it could be caused by the fact that I have split the form into several div "pages". I've also tried to make next/submit buttons rather than "Next, next, next ... submit" so that I can store the temporary data in the session, unsuccessfully.

I reworked my whole strategy into a code that hides the question divs that are not active. By this I mean I have one div with data-role set to page, and within it I have several divs with data-roles of content that are hidden/shown by clicking through the form with the next button. I managed to make a small sample form this way that submits the whole form and gets printed out perfectly with some PHP code. However I have yet to successfully validate this version. I can only get my script to validate the last page, and even then it requires ALL checkboxes to be checked, which is pointless. When I tried to implement this version into my real project I could not get it to submit to the .php script at all, but that might just be some syntax error that I will keep looking for.

So, have anyone done anything similar? I'm looking for potential other strategies to solve this issue, or perhaps someone has a theory as to why my aforementioned attemps have failed. Seems Ajax form submits are hard to get working within jQuery Mobile?

Also in case someone can spot a flaw in this I've attached this code that I use for submission, is there an easy way to make this into a function? Or is that pointless?

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
            $("#submit").click(function() 
            {
                var data_string = $('#form').serialize();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'add.php',
                    data:data_string,
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        $("#answers").html(response);
                    }
                });         
            })
    });
```

I also use this function during window.onload to generate the poll with a lengthy .php script. Basically it generates the questions as , every other question variety has only name="answers[question_id]".

```
function getQuestions(id)
        {
            var xmlhttp = getHttpRequestObj();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","poll2.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="form">
  <div data-role="content" id="form'.$page.'" class="section">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true" id="'.$question_id.'">
      <input type="checkbox" name="answers['.$question_id.']['.$alt_id.']" id="'.$question_id.'_'.$alt_id.'" value="'.$alt_id.'"/>
        <label for="'.$question_id.'_'.$alt_id.'">'.$alt_desc.'</label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" id="next" onClick="toggleVisibility(\'form'.($page+1).'\')" class="next-btn"/>
  </div>
```

The last page has this code instead of the next button:

```
</div><input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn"/></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, hiding the other options and open one by one is a better way (also called multi step form).

For validation, you can do it in client side with javascript or use ajax which triggers on appropriate event (you don't need to submit it for validation) and validates in server side.

You are in right track. The issue i see here is how you'l do the validation but that'l depend upon how your form is structured.

Comment: By hiding the other options and open one by one you mean the show/hide div version I made? It sure does feel better, but I can get the jQuery Validator script to work properly with it - which is weird because all the data from all the steps are sent, just not validated even though they all have the class="required" attached to them. I might need to look into ways to design my own version. Other than that it's nice to hear I'm on the right track! But could it be beneficial to submit to session data for each step rather than just send it all at once upon completion?

Comment: Updated question a bit with some more code, perhaps that can clarify it some more.

Comment: Could it be problematic to have the .php script generate the poll? Seems that I cannot submit once I make .php scripts to generate the polls, but the ones made directly in .html seems to work just fine (except the validation ofcourse).